# creating a calculated field to visualize performance

Tags: looker-studio

I'm trying to create a simple calculated field where an existing field is divided by another existing field. I have uploaded a screenshot to show the fields in question. The field was created by saying:

```
Sales Count/Perx
```

But the result in the field `Perx Perf` is way off. I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong though. Any assistance will be greatly appreciated.

**Screenshot 1:**
[image: Screenshot]

**Screenshot 2 - New Field**:
[image: Screenshot_2_New_Field]

Comment: Could you elaborate by providing a publicly editable Google Data Studio Report of the scenario (using sample data that shows 1) Input values (~10 rows of data) 2) Expected output 3) Optionally (but preferably) an attempt at solving the issue so that there is a specific problem)? It would help users visualise the issue and test out suggestions on a specific use case. Without a **[Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)** it would be difficult to pinpoint a suggestion and the issue, e.g. Data Set, Data Source, Report, Fields, Chart Configuration

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that Sales Count is Count and Perx is Sum, but in your formula you the using them both as Count. If this is the problem the solution might be to change formula to

```
SUM(Sales Count * Perx)
```